# Looking for a Solar System Simulator including the smaller celestial body, for macOS

Tags: internal-consistency, solar-system, virtual-reality

I am researching for a sci-fi story that will happen in 2136.

There will be a lot of traveling in the **Inner Solar System** and I need to know the relative distances between two objects. Also, I would like to know specific positions of "smaller" celestial bodies in our Solar System.
An example can be the dwarf planet Ceres and other big rocks in the Main Asteroid Belt.

If possible, I would like the tool to be **open-source**.

I am looking for a tool like NASA's Eyes. That tool can give a detailed and global views on the Solar System. It shows the orbits of different bodies. In addition, it lets me play with time and distance. **And most importantly, it can give me the distance between two bodies** (https://eyes.nasa.gov/).

The main problem with NASA's app is that it only let me travel until 2050 :/

PS: I've asked this question in the Astronomy StackExchange. Probably the Worldbuilding one is a better place because I've seen similar questions over here.

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Universe Sandbox - $30 - great tool for playing with real or imagined solar systems. Lets you develop more "what if" scenarios, and see what happens. Or just load up our solar system "as-is."

Celestia - Open source - tool for visualizing our solar system. (I haven't tried it in a while.)

Comment: Seconding Celestia; it's a little old, but there's loads of free community addons and it's easy to add ephemerides for other objects if for some reason the base program doesn't have the objects you're looking for.

Comment: I also noticed, @quasi, that you said in the astronomy StackExchange question that Celestia doesn't show distances between objects. It can; just fly right next to one object and then select another. Also, it allows you to enable visible orbits for at least the planets, last I checked, which can be part of the way towards a "global view" of the solar system like you asked (just move to the Sun's north pole at a few AU, for example).

Comment: @parasoup, I will give Ceelstia another try. Thx!